# UseExceptionHandler vs GlobalExceptionMiddleware

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I am just trying to understand while ASP.Net Core 2.x offers the possibility of app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error") [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-5.0), and even UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-5.0) Do we still need to implement a global exception handling middleware like what is being discuss in [here](https://medium.com/@antarikshverma/how-to-handle-errors-with-the-inbuilt-middleware-in-asp-net-core-web-api-7c5aab0ec7ca)? or even [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/brandonh/using-middleware-to-trap-exceptions-in-asp-net-core?source=docs) which is know by GlobalExceptionMiddleware and needs to be registered in the most button layer of chain of layers in .Net Core

Comment: UseExceptionHandler log the error and redirect to a custom error HTML page, it's designed to web application. The custom midleware suggested in the medium article return JSON content, this is destined to API.

Comment: Handle errors in ASP.NET Core web APIs which has discussed in (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/handle-errors?view=aspnetcore-5.0#exception-handler) also offers to use UseExceptionHandler. Doesn`t this mean UseExceptionHandler is also destined to be used in Web APIs?

Comment: My bad, UseExceptionHandler is also destined to API. Then, I don't understand the goal of the medium article... In my company will have a custom midleware to log complementary information on some error. Maybe UseExceptionHandler is sufficient to most common case (log + generic error result).

Comment: This is also what I am not understanding :-/

Comment: Maybe you can directly ask to the writter in comment section below the article.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated the Microsoft [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/handle-errors?view=aspnetcore-5.0#custom-middleware-to-handle-exceptions) to make this question clear.